# Rcpp not installing properly, R2.15.2

Tags: r, rcpp

Installing `Rcpp` on Linux Ubuntu 12.04,   with R2.15.2
NB both R and rcpp were installed yesterday; so I would expect the most recent versions, but `Rcpp` is installed as an out of date version!

```
> old.packages()

     Package LibPath                   Installed  Built    ReposVer  
Rcpp "Rcpp"  "/usr/lib/R/site-library" "0.9.9"    "2.14.1" "0.10.2"  
rgl  "rgl"   "/usr/lib/R/site-library" "0.92.798" "2.12.1" "0.92.894"
     Repository                                 
Rcpp "http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/src/contrib"
rgl  "http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/src/contrib"
> update.packages("Rcpp")
```

As the last line shows, it has not updated the package `Rcpp` at all; What is causing this and what can I do to resolve this?

NB Tried re-installing from two different repositories, both of which claimed to have the most recent version 0.10.2 of rcpp.

Regards

Jefe

Answer (score 4):

You simply misunderstand.

The Rcpp you have is from **Ubuntu** and installed via `apt-get` et al.  That version is frozen when the distro freezes.  This is similar to how gcc, emacs, ... are not the most current version *available now* but the version taken when the distro was made.
And as an aside, even that Ubuntu version is now dated by one release as 12.10 is out...

So your question title is wrong. The version you have is installed *correctly as the version that is part of Ubuntu 12.04.*  Makes sense now?

Now, if you install Rcpp from CRAN via `install.packages()` you will get the current version, idem for rgl.

(And there is also a PPA on launchpad which likely to have both as prebuild .deb packages.)

Lastly, and explained before, the path `/usr/lib/R/site-library` is for the `r-cran-*` packages you install as .deb files where `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` is for your local
installs from R itself.  Because of that split, the output of `old.packages()` that is driven from the former path, eg `/usr/lib/R/site-library` is bound to behind because it is managed by the distribution, here Ubuntu.  You chose the distro for the stability of its components -- and you are free to augment it with CRAN packages in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`.  And that is definitely a feature.

Witness this from my Ubuntu box:

```
R> old.packages(lib.loc="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/")
NULL
R>
```

Comment: I had also run install.packages() prior to my previous post, and restarted R subsequently (with sudo R ) prior to checking the old.packages().  I have now checked the lib.loc "".." and yes ut appears that I have both versions of rcpp installed; but the command library(Rcpp) is picking up the older library. How to I point it to the new version?

Comment: just tried library(Rcpp,lib.loc="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/"), and the C++ code worked, ie picking up the correct version of the library; I assume this is now necessary for all other libraries?

Comment: What does '.libPaths()' return?  You should have three entries, with that one being the first and hence the default -- that way `/usr/local` has precedence.  We set `.libPaths()` via `/etc/R/Renvinron`, a softlink to the file in `$R_HOME/etc/Renviron`.  Could you have (accidentally) overwritten this?